# Mysql: правильное составление запроса двухтабличного запроса

Tags: mysql

Как в данной ситуации правильно составить запрос.Есть 2 таблицы `social_networks` и `users_social_networks_accounts`.Запрос должен вернуть все социальные сети id которого равен текущему залогиненному в систему или или если в таблице user_social_networks_accounts  у него вообще нет записей.То есть в любом случае должны возвращаться все соц. сети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT sc.name, sc.icon, us.*
FROM social_networks sc
LEFT JOIN users_social_networks_accounts us ON sc.id = us.social_id
WHERE us.user_id = '12030' or us.user_id is null
```

Данный запрос вытаскивает все кроме фейсбука,так как для него есть запись в таблице `users_social_networks_accounts`.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN и условие " or us.user_id is null" не нужно

Comment: Возвращает пустой запрос,и разве left outer join Это не одно и тоже чтол и left join?

Answer (score 1):

Соединение `LEFT JOIN` по определению возвращает все записи таблицы, расположенной в левой части ключевого слова. Поэтому условие 'or us.user_id is null' явно избыточное. Однако, чтобы выбрать информацию только для текущего пользователя, необходимо отфильтровать данные таблицы `users_social_networks_accounts`. Лучше всего это сделать через вложенный запрос, который следует подставить в FROM-выражение вместо таблицы `users_social_networks_accounts`

```
SELECT
  sc.name,
  sc.icon,
  us.*
FROM
  social_networks sc
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     *
   FROM 
     users_social_networks_accounts
   WHERE
     user_id = '12030') us
ON
  sc.id = us.social_id
```